# storing split string into array using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am using awk-split to split string and to store it into array.

I'm not able to use that array inside script. it's showing empty array.

```
echo $pre_session_cmds | awk '{split($0,cmd_array,"};")} END {for(n in cmd_array){ print cmd_array[n] }}'

for element in "${cmd_array[@]}"
do
    echo "command is $element"
done
```

issue:
print with awk printing elements correctly but accessing in for loop showing array as empty

Comment: That array `cmd_array` only exists in the awk process. It cannot be referenced from the shell script like you seem to be doing. You need to reference it in awk or print it out from awk into another array in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `bash` solution:

```
cmd_array=($(echo $pre_session_cmds |sed -e "s/};/ /g"))
```

Or just

```
for element in $(echo ${pre_session_cmds}|sed -e "s/};/ /g");do
   echo $element
done
```

Comment: *Pure* removed ;)

Comment: `for element in ${pre_session_cmds//\};/ }; do` would be much better. But it's not equivalent to OP's requirement (since this also splits on elements of `IFS`—and, moreover, is subject to pathname expansion).

Answer (score 0):

Just print it in awk:

```
echo $pre_session_cmds | awk '{ split($0,cmd_array,"};") } 
                          END { for(n in cmd_array) 
                                    print "command is " cmd_array[n] }'
```

Answer (score 0):

The array that you are creating inside awk belongs to only awk.
It does not exist when you come out of awk.
Instead do this:

```
declare -a arr
arr=( $(your code here) )
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[*]}
```

So it will turn out to be:

```
declare -a arr
arr=( $(echo $pre_session_cmds | awk '{split($0,cmd_array,"};")} END {for(n in cmd_array){ print cmd_array[n] }}') )
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[*]}
```

I haven't tested it though.